# Unit Testing Branch Partially Covered Using VectorCAST

Tags: c, unit-testing, vectorcast

I am using VectorCAST to test the code, and one branch is partially covered and I am just asking if there is a way to make it fully covered.

If I have a structure that it's elements are one bit in size.

and I have a code like this

```
if(structure.bit.line1 == 0x01)
{
   //some code
}
else if(structure.bit.line1 == 0x00)
{
   //some code
}
```

I know that in the first `if` condition, I can make it fully covered by setting `structure.bit.line1` to `0x00` to satisfy the `FALSE` coverage and `0x01` to satisfy the `TRUE` coverage, but the next `else if` I only can test its `TRUE` state, so is there is a way to test the `FALSE` state.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm just curious about what is the underlying type of line1?  Can you set it to 0x02 ?  Otherwise, the else if could simply be "else"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use in the code else instead of using else if that will solve this problem
but lets say it's mandatory to do that you can modify the code as following :

```
if(structure.bit.line1 == 0x01)
{
   //some code
}
#ifndef VECTORCAST
else if(structure.bit.line1 == 0x00)
#else
if(structure.bit.line1 == 0x00)
#endif
{
   //some code
}
```